# VBA UserForm: Copy and Paste based on Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am creating a UserForm in VBA that will look up a specific box size from a separate sheet that contains over 3000 unique box sizes and returns into another sheet only the corresponding columns for that size.

I have tried many types of loops with for each and for which simply didn't work. So I tried to create a copy and paste method that will copy all the rows where the first column matches the value from my Combobox. The issue that I continue to run into is with my line of code with my destination/paste range. I get run-time error 1004 "You can't paste here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size".

This is the VBA code I currently have in my UserForm once the Enter Button is clicked. For reference, the sheet that contains all the data that I want to search for is Lookup Draft and the sheet where I want to paste the matching rows is Box Lookup Data.

```
Sub EnterButton_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim datawks As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Box Lookup Data")
Set datawks = Worksheets("Lookup Draft")

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

   'Find the last used row
   With datawks
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   'first row number to paste values
   With ws
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   'copy from datawks to ws
   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With datawks
           If .Cells(i, 1).Value = ComboBox.Text Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("B" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i

End Sub
```

I have tried to change the line of code containing destination to a cell reference but that also does not work. I want the pasted range to include all the matching rows, not just the first match found- which is the issue I was running into before trying out copy/paste.

The sheet where I want to paste has 5 labeled columns: (B)Box Size, (C)Customer, (D)Price, (E)Quantity, and (F)Order Date

Any thoughts?

Comment: One suspicion: You can't copy an entire row (beginning in column A) to a cell in column B, because the entire row won't fit in the remaining columns.

Comment: Hi David, even if there are only 5 columns to copy?

Comment: So it seems you need to somehow restrict the range that you're copying. I suspect that you absolutely do not need the "entire row" as given by `.Rows(i)`.

Comment: A range defined by `Rows(i)` necessarily implies **ALL** columns in that specific row.

Comment: `.Cells(i,1).Resize(,5).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("B" & j)`

Comment: If there are only 5 columns to copy, then you need to define the range to be copied as those 5 columns only. Then it should work.

Comment: @SJR 's response, assuming you need the 5 columns A through E. If you need some other columns, you'll need to modify.

Comment: I see what you mean, that way the sizes would match right? So instead should I try with datawks ... .range((i,1),(i,5)) or something to that extent?

Comment: As @DavidZemens says, the line I posted will copy e.g.A5 to E5.

Comment: DavidZemmens and SJR thank you!! I tried SJR's edit and it worked!